# Управление временами файлов

Tags: windows, файлы, winapi

В Far manager если открыть диалог свойств файла, то видно четыре времени

- Время последней записи
- Время создания
- Время последнего доступа
- Время изменения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С первыми тремя все понятно, они управляются функциями `GetFileTime`/`SetFileTime`. А что такое `Время изменения`? Как его можно прочитать и установить?

Comment: видимо это время последней записи в файл.

Comment: @PRODIGY Допустим. Хотя есть `время последней записи`. А как его получить/установить?

Comment: Get/SetFileInformationByHandle()

Comment: @PRODIGY Спасибо. Похоже на правду. Хотя сам Far вызывает SetBasicInformationFile